# Receiving Error when Trying to render array elements

Tags: reactjs, components, state, use-effect, react-props

I am receiving the following errors when trying to render list elements from an array :

react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {common, official, nativeName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

and

react_devtools_backend.js:4061 The above error occurred in the component

```
at li
at ul
at div
at Countries (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:349:23)
at div
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:93:80)
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

I am trying to map through an array that I pass as a prop to my Countries Component, then render the name property from each object in the form of a list item but I am not sure why I am receiving this error. See my code Below:

```
Countries.js Component

import React from 'react';

export default function Countries(props) {
    return (
        <div>
         
            <ul>
             {props.countries.map(country=><li style={{listStyleType: 'none'}} key={country.fifa}>{country.name}</li>)}
             </ul>
         </div>)
}
```

```
App.js  Component

import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Countries from './Countries';


function App() {

const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('effect')
  axios
    .get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
    .then(response => {
      console.log('promise fulfilled', response.data)

      setCountries(response.data.slice(0,10))

    })
}, [])



 return (
  
    <div className="App">
   
  <Countries countries={countries}/>
  
    </div>
  );


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`country.name` is an object. Use `country.name.common` or `JSON.stringify(country.name)`